# Why are two identical emojis not equal?

Tags: javascript, unicode, emoji

I have to validate the user's emoji input and perform a comparison to see what they entered. However, I've started noticing that several emojis look identical, but are not equal. Take a look at the example below, `moonA` has a length of 2, but `moonB` is 3:

```js
var moonA = "";
var moonB = "️";

console.log(moonA == moonB);
console.log("Moon A:", moonA.length);
console.log("Moon B:", moonB.length);
```

What could be causing this discrepancy? I've looked at them up close in both Windows and iOS, and they look exactly the same on both systems. Why are there two versions of the same emoji?

Comment: Looking the same does not make them equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[What Unicode character is this?](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html) identifies them as:

```
moonA = ""
    U+1F315 : FULL MOON SYMBOL

moonB = "️"
    U+1F315 : FULL MOON SYMBOL
    U+FE0F : VARIATION SELECTOR-16 [VS16] {emoji variation selector}
```

Comment: To add: `moonB` makes explicit that you want a coloured version of emoji. On `moonA` some systems may print it just as black-and-white moon (you can force this bahaviour with VS15).